# JavaFX Cross Platform start on boot

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to have a feature for the user to select if he wants to start or not the application on OS boot.
It must be cross-platform possible.

Unfortunately i don't know what would be the best technique for this.

---

Do i have to implement this on my own?

Could a wrapper do the job and which one has a cross-platform support?

Please tell me your advice's.